# Can you use multiplication for commands in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, fuzzing

I am trying to make a simple script to start multiple fuzzers with AFL, I am prompting the users for the amount of fuzzers they want to start, storing the variable, and then want to issue the same command the number of times they specified.

```
I.E., "afl-fuzz -i /input -o /output ./binary fuzzer1 @@"
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe, if you want to run your process in parallel in the background?

```sh
for ((i=0;i<${nb_process};i++)); do
    afl-fuzz -i /input -o /output.$i ... &
done
```

Remove the `&` if you want to run them one after the other in the foreground.

If you want to run your jobs in parallel with different files for input, a solution to consider might be xargs:

```sh
find . -name "*input*" -print0 | xargs -0 --max-procs=16 --max-args=3 afl-fuzz ...
```

(See man page for `xargs` for details.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `seq`, which "prints a sequence of numbers".

So if you have your number in `$num` :

```
for i in $(seq 1 $num); do
    afl-fuzz -i /input -o /output-$i ./binary ... &
done
```

`&` makes it run in the background, so all your processes start immediately

Comment: Depending on what `/input` and `/output` mean I'm guessing you would want to use a different output one (at least) for each run, like in the other answer.

Comment: @tripleee : yes, I guess you are right, though I don't know what `afl-fuzz` actually does. Corrected the answer. Thanks.